# Implementing dynamic query using linq functions

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to implement a block of code which can Dynamically add a where clause to a linq query. It totally helps me to consider only full text boxes
during my search process and jump over empty controls.Now the problem is, Despite all conditions which i have added to my Linq query, **It returns all rows and ignores where clauses.**

what is the reason and how can i avoid this problem ?

Here i have a simple abstract BaseEntity class which is contained only one field called Id :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

My EmailEntity class is inherited from this BaseEntity :

```
    public class EmailEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
        public string Hint { get; set; }
        public EmailGroup? EmailGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

This is where i create my query :

```
 private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mails = new List<EmailEntity>();    
            using (var op = new OperationContext())
            {
                var query = op.EmailEntities;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmailTxt.Text))
                    query.Where(item => item.Address == SearchEmailTxt.Text);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmailIdTxt.Text))
                    query.Where(item => item.Id == Convert.ToInt16(SearchEmailIdTxt.Text));
                if (SearchEmailGroupCombo.SelectedItem != null)
                    query.Where(item => item.EmailGroup.ToString() == SearchEmailGroupCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
                var result=query.ToList();
                result.ForEach(mails.Add);
                EmailDataGrid.ItemsSource = mails;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `query.Where` returns query back and you ignore the result, which brings you to begining. You should change your code like `query = query.Where(....);`

```
private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mails = new List<EmailEntity>();    
    using (var op = new OperationContext())
    {
        IQueryable<EmailEntity> query = op.EmailEntities;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmailTxt.Text))
            query = query.Where(item => item.Address == SearchEmailTxt.Text);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchEmailIdTxt.Text))
            query = query.Where(item => item.Id == Convert.ToInt16(SearchEmailIdTxt.Text));
        if (SearchEmailGroupCombo.SelectedItem != null)
            query = query.Where(item => item.EmailGroup.ToString() == SearchEmailGroupCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
        var result=query.ToList();
        result.ForEach(mails.Add);
        EmailDataGrid.ItemsSource = mails;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now I have a compile time error says : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<NB.Entity.EmailEntity>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<NB.Entity.EmailEntity>'.

Comment: @T.shaped try using either `var query = op.EmailEntities.AsQueryable();` or `IQueryable<EmailEntity> query = op.EmailEntities;`

Comment: @AdilMammadov You have my vote, but why don't you update the answer with one of those :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are right, answer must have been updated for future users. Thanks